# Selecting textpathes in Chrome is not selecting the intended text compared to Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I would like to know why the Chrome is behaving completely different to Firefox in terms of the **textpathes** highlighting. I **toggle** a **class** with **jQuery**, so that the mouseovered text element is highlighted. In Firefox all is fine, so I'm wondering why Chrome behaves so different. I have prepared a jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/5uc17jwr/16/ for testing.

I marked the area where the mouse was with a **red dot**.

So if you test it in **Firefox** it works perfectly:

[image]

When you compare that with **Chrome** you can see that the mouseovered element is never accessable:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that is that Chrome behaving different in terms of the **bounding box**. Currently there is no solution for this. Just use Firefox instead =)